# How to remove reversed values from 2 columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a table with values as follows

```
Actor-1  Actor-2  Value
A        B        2
A        C        1
B        A        2
B        C        2
```

Since the values of A - B and B - A are same, I want to remove one of those instances, giving me a table

```
Actor-1  Actor-2  Value
A        B        2
A        C        1
B        C        2
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding a column that puts them in some canonical sorted order and then delete duplicate rows based on that column.

```
let
    Source = <Your Data Source>
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom",
                         each Text.Combine(List.Sort({[Actor1],[Actor2]}),","),type text),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

The key part is

`Text.Combine(List.Sort({[Actor1],[Actor2]}),",")`

This creates a list out of the two actor columns `{[Actor1],[Actor2]}`, sorts the list into alphabetical order with `List.Sort` and then concatenates them into a single string with `Text.Combine`.

---

You can skip combining the text if you prefer since remove duplicates works on lists too:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom",
                    each List.Sort({[Actor1],[Actor2]}),type list),
```